# Would like to manage a DSL and Satellite Internet Connection

Tags: networking, router, internet, bridge-router

My parents live in the country and have very poor and unreliable DSL (Frontier) service.   They are considering getting Satellite Internet (HughesNet or Exceed).   Because the Satellite has monthly usage caps, I would like to manage/direct traffic based on performance.   Use DSL first is working well as the first choice, then roll over to Satellite as needed.  They are remote so I am looking for stable/simple configuration not optimum performance.

Each connection will have its own modem (vendor provided), which I should be able to assign a static IP. I am looking develop a solution to manage/balance the dual internet connections - that is also easy to manage.

Suggestions on a technical/approach configuration.

Comment: You may have better luck finding an answer to this question on Server Fault. You could grab an old PC (with multiple NIC's) and install PFSense and set up rules to route certain types of traffic out certain ports. Any solution I imaging would be hard working remotely.

Comment: This question is not on topic since your requesting a hardware recommendation.  It can be salvaged once that specific request of us suggesting product is removed.

Answer (score 0):

[TP-LINK TL-R470T+](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005SYQBN8) is an inexpensive option with 3 additionally configurable ports (wan/lan) although i don't have any experience in the setup of this kind of thing TP-LINK has always been a stable and quiet cheap solution.

**Edit:** Since your main concern is stability, i would refrain from trying to build little DIY-Solutions. The configuration is generally much broader/deeper than using a router with this kind of functionality. In addition to that, you don't really want to be troubleshooting 10 components when the system breaks...

Comment: The device looks like a good fit, and for around $59 is reasonably priced.